# Cant recall PLAYER ID/Retrieving password problem

Tags: pokemon-go

I signed in using my Pokemon Trainer Club Account. When I went to the link for retrieving my password, it asked for my "player id." I can't recall my player id. Is there any way to retrieve it as well?

Comment: I dunno. Search your mail?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. After banging my head for half an hour, I just realized that it is only the e-mail address that is required to fill in. There is a small icon showing required fields. It is only the e-mail address that is marked as such.

Trick is to just fill in your e-mail address and leave all the other fields empty.